# Shader GLSL file Not compiling

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I am writing my first program using OpenGL, and I have gotten to the point where I am trying to get it to compile my extremely simple shader program. I always get the error that it failed to compile the shader. I use the following code to compile the shader:

```
struct Shader
{
    const char*  filename;
    GLenum       type;
    GLchar*      source;
 };
...
static char* readShaderSource(const char* shaderFile)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(shaderFile, "r");

    if ( fp == NULL ) { return NULL; }

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(fp);

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    char* buf = new char[size + 1];
    fread(buf, 1, size, fp);

    buf[size] = '\0';
    fclose(fp);

    return buf;
}
...
Shader s;
s.filename = "<name of shader file>";
s.type = GL_VERTEX_SHADER;
s.source = readShaderSource( s.filename );
GLuint shader = glCreateShader( s.type );
glShaderSource( shader, 1, (const GLchar**) &s.source, NULL );
glCompileShader( shader );
```

And my shader file source is as follows:

```
#version 150

in vec4 vPosition;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vPosition;
}
```

I have also tried replacing "in" with "attribute" as well as deleting the version line. Nothing compiles.
Note:My actual C program compiles and runs. The shader program that runs on the GPU is what is failing to compile.

I have also made sure to download my graphics card's latest driver. I have an NVIDIA 8800 GTS 512;

Any ideas on how to get my shader program (written in GLSL) to compile?

Comment: What does the [info log](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetShaderInfoLog.xml) say? Was the file loaded correctly (so `s.source` contains the correct shader source)? Looks reasonable otherwise.

Comment: You can use gDebugger ( which is free ) to get insight about errors, fix and retry without restarting application

Comment: Jeremy, how are you checking that compilation failed?  Since your code seems ok, maybe you are simply checking compilation status incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

As wrote in comments, does compile shader output anything to console? To my surprise, while I was using ATI, I got message that shader program compiled successfuly, however when I started using Nvidia, I was staring at screen for first time, because nothing got output... however shaders were working. So maybe you are successfuly compiling and just don't take it? And if they are not working in context you try to use shader program and nothing happens, I think you're missing the linking of shader (it may be further in code however). Google has some good answers on how to correctly perform every step, you can compare your code to this [example](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/loading.php). I also made an interface for working whit shaders, you can take a look my [UniShader](http://box.net/s/2vdkti7f2vtyhvryxcdf). Project lacks english documentation and is mainly used for GPGPU, but you can easily load any shader, and the code itself is written whit english naming, so it should be quite comfortable. Look in folder UniShader in that zip for source codes. There are also few examples, the one named Ukazkovy program na GPGPU got also source included so you can look how to use those classes.. good luck!